# Cannot query for a long string in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an active record `Song` model with a `songhash` field (string(255)) that contains a Sha2 hash. When I try to find a song via the following code nothing gets returned:

```
song = Song.all.first
song2 = Song.where(songhash: song.songhash).first
# song is a valid object with a songhash set, but song2 is nil!
```

If I do the same thing however with a "like" query it works:

```
song = Song.all.first
song2 = Song.where("songhash like ?", song.songhash).first
# song2 is a valid object now
song2.songhash == song.songhash
# the equation is true
```

I fear it has something to do with string encodings but I have no idea why this string could possibly have encoding issues: `61a9761b9ebd543b72c5ccf2ab6db198b067f7cf7f8412ee6e9c14b19611bc80`

I'm using rails 3.1 with sqlite db.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What does `Song.find_by_songhash(song.songhash)` return?

Comment: unfortunately it returns nil :-(

Comment: How are you generating the hash?  There is no whitespace present in the hash is there?  Have you tried using the hash directly, not as a variable?

Comment: I tried to use it directly but even then it was not found. The code to generate the hash is: `songhash = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{self.title}#{self.album}#{self.artist}#{self.year}").to_s` so nothing really exciting.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the to_s will probably throw an error as Digest::SHA2.hexdigest returns a string and there is no to_s method on a stirng.

Comment: Actually I changed that back and forth many times but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Gazler to_s is declared by Object and String is an Object. So you can call to_s on a string as many time as you want.

Comment: @derhackler Which database do you use?

Comment: @basgys `ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("No you can't").to_s` `NoMethodError: undefined method to_s' for #<String:0x0000000113f780>`

Comment: @Gazler: Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("No you can't").to_s actually works in my rails console.

Comment: @Gazler 1.9.2p180 :004 > "I'm a String".to_s
 => "I'm a String"

Comment: @derhackler Can we see the SQL statement generated by Song.where(songhash: song.songhash).first ?

Comment: sure. this statement does not work: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" IN ('PlaylistSong') AND "songs"."title" = 'ts' AND "songs"."playlist_id" = 980190962 AND "songs"."songhash" = '44ad63f60af0f6db6fdde6d5186ef78176367df261fa06be3079b6c80c8adba4'

Comment: actually its these two: SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" IN ('PlaylistSong') AND "songs"."songhash" = '61a9761b9ebd543b72c5ccf2ab6db198b067f7cf7f8412ee6e9c14b19611bc80'   -   and with the like clause: SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" IN ('PlaylistSong') AND (songhash like '61a9761b9ebd543b72c5ccf2ab6db198b067f7cf7f8412ee6e9c14b19611bc80')

Comment: Try something like this : Song.where(['UPPER(songhash) = ?', song.songhash.upcase]).first but I doubt that is the problem... I'm wondering if you stored chars like carriage returns or something like that in your database. Have you already tried to access your database with a GUI like Navicat to see how your hash looks like in your database?

Comment: And by the way, are Ruby and SQLite both in UTF-8 or at least the same charset?

Comment: very interesting! the upper variant works. however looking at the strings i see no difference.

Comment: Have you found something new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help of @gazler and @basgys I was able to track down the problem:

It is in fact an encoding problem caused by the Digest::Sha2#hexdigest function. It returns a string that is encoded as ASCII-8BIT. When storing this in the database it seems to be converted automatically to a UTF-8 string (I check that by running a `select hex(songhash) from songs` query). However when using the string in the query, it does not seem to do that conversion.

Internally ruby seems to handle the different encoding conversions automatically. That is why `"abc"=="abc"` although they may have different encoding.

I'm sure that this is not expected behavior, however I don't know if it is a bug - and if it is a bug whether it is somewhere within ActiveRecord, the SQLite Driver, or SQLite itself.

My solution is now to append a `.encode("UTF-8")` to the result of the digest function.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

SQL statements generated

```
 # With = / It doesn't work
 SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" 
 IN ('PlaylistSong') AND "songs"."songhash" =
 '61a9761b9ebd543b72c5ccf2ab6db198b067f7cf7f8412ee6e9c14b19611bc80'

 # With like / It works
 SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" 
 IN ('PlaylistSong') AND (songhash like 
 '61a9761b9ebd543b72c5ccf2ab6db198b067f7cf7f8412ee6e9c14b19611bc80')

 # With upper / It works
 SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."type" 
 IN ('PlaylistSong') AND (UPPER(songhash) = 
 '61A9761B9EBD543B72C5CCF2AB6DB198B067F7CF7F8412EE6E9C14B19611BC80')
```

The following statements work:

```
 Song.where(['UPPER(songhash) = ?', song.songhash.upcase]).first
 Song.where(['songhash like ?', song.songhash]).first
```

**UPPER** and **LIKE** are both case insensitive

**SQLite documentation**

> The LIKE operator does a pattern matching comparison. (A bug: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are **beyond** the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.) [See more](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

**To investigage**

1. Charset equals? (Rails - SQLite)
2. String stored potentially dirty (carriage returns, ...)